# Clear Banner Notification When Tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, push-notification

I have noticed that when I select a push notification for my app from notification center, that notification no longer appears in the list of notifications. However, when I receive a notification and tap the banner right away, the app opens as it should, but when I pull down to view the notification center, that notification is still there. I have the following push handling code in my delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    //Presenting view controllers...

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    // Extract the notification data
    NSDictionary *notificationPayload = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if(notificationPayload)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

    // when you tap on any of notification this delegate method will call...
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use following to remove all notifications

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        [self clearNotifications];
    } 

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        [self clearNotifications];
    }

- (void)clearNotifications
    {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
```

Comment: This does not work. The notification still appears in notification center after the banner is tapped.

Comment: Remove following from all places :                                              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];

Comment: The notification still appears in notification center after the banner is tapped.

Comment: You are tapping the banner notification as soon as it is delivered? I am not talking about tapping notifications in the notification center, those work fine.

Comment: this will clear all the notification. It'll not just clear the selected notification.

Comment: Yes Jay , This code will clear all notification. If you don't want to clear all notifications don't add this code . Selected notification will be cleared by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this delegate method:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
     [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The notification still appears in notification center after the banner is tapped. I forgot to add that I already had this method implemented.